# Java - Handle a set of constant strings within code

Tags: java

I want to create a collection of constant strings like below for my program.

> Seattle-WA, Salem-OR, San Francisco-CA, Oakland-CA, San Jose-CA, Denver-CO, Fremont-CA, Boston-MA, Washington-DC, Phoenix-AZ, Santa Rosa-CA, Vancouver-WA, Fargo-ND, Sioux Falls-SD

The above string should be searchable and and I don't want to add each string manually. What would be an elegant way of doing it?

Comment: A few possibilities: Use an enum, use a properties file, hard-code the values as final string constants.  What exactly do you have in mind?

Comment: If you have fixed number of constants then go for enum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Java Enums. An Enum type is a special data type that enables for a variable to be a set of predefined constants.

Example: Let's write an Enum to make Driver names predefined constants:

```
public enum DbType {
MYSQL("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"), POSTGRESQL("org.postgresql.Driver");

private final String driverClassName;

private DbType(final String driverClassName) {
    this.driverClassName = driverClassName;
}

public String getDriverClassName() {
    return driverClassName;
}
}
```

Refer below link, how to use Enums in real projects:

https://www.javaguides.net/2018/06/enums-in-java.html

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing is to use enum.

If you are using spring you can load the comma-separated values into the list from a property file.

@Value("${mylist}")
    private static List myList;

in properties file

mylist=Seattle-WA, Salem-OR, San Francisco-CA, Oakland-CA, San Jose-CA, Denver-CO, Fremont-CA, Boston-MA, Washington-DC, Phoenix-AZ, Santa Rosa-CA, Vancouver-WA, Fargo-ND, Sioux Falls-SD